# STL alternative for memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, memory-leaks, stl

I am very new bee to C++ coding and STL library usage. I was quite interested on using STL library on my C++ program which I was developing. But recently I tried using Visual Leak detector and found many leaks which are specifically where ever I used STL library and `new` operator.

Since it is an runtime application I also found the CPU memory keeps increasing when I run the code for 4-5 days continuously. Learning on some of the forums and other noted, I understood that I need to delete/erase the content inside the `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, `std:set` before calling its corresponding `clear`. 
My question here is if I do all those on the destructor calls which are never gonna called (since my programmer never going to STOP) will the STL library create memory leak every time I access it?

Is there an alternative for this?

Example: `common.h`

```
struct stTagElem_t {
    uint32_t  m_unOffset;
    uint32_t  m_unArraySize;
    string    m_acTagName;
    string    m_acTagValue;
    string    m_acDataType;
} ;

typedef std::unordered_map<uint8_t, stTagElem_t> tagsList_t;

struct stMappingElem_t {
    uint16_t     m_unMemSize;
    tagsList_t   m_stTagsList;
    string       m_acEventName;
    string       m_acMapTypeName;
} ;

typedef std::unordered_map<uint32_t, stMappingElem_t> eventDataMap_t;
```

dataMapManager.cpp //declared as global list since dataMapManager.cpp has all static functions

```
eventDataMap_t sm_eventDataMapList;
```

So When I use Visual Leak Detector It says the following:

```
---------- Block 596 at 0x00DE8DB8: 120 bytes ----------


Leak Hash: 0xB26C3A34, Count: 1, Total 120 bytes
  Call Stack (TID 11580):
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xmemory0 (977): example.exe!std::_Wrap_alloc<std::allocator<std::_List_node<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,void *> > >::allocate()
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (730): example.exe!std::_List_alloc<std::_List_base_types<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t> > > >::_Buynode0() + 0x11 bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (716): example.exe!std::_List_alloc<std::_List_base_types<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t> > > >::_Buyheadnode()
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (649): example.exe!std::_List_alloc<std::_List_base_types<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t> > > >::_List_alloc<std::_List_base_types<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,std::al() + 0x8 bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (826): example.exe!std::_List_buy<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t> > >::_List_buy<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappin()
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\list (899): example.exe!std::list<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t> > >::list<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t> >()
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xhash (197): example.exe!std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<unsigned __int64,stMappingElem_t,std::_Uhash_compare<unsigned __int64,std::hash<unsigned __int64>,std::equal_to<unsigned __int64> >,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t> >,0> >::_Hash<std::_Umap_tra() + 0xF bytes
    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\unordered_map (119): example.exe!std::unordered_map<unsigned __int64,stMappingElem_t,std::hash<unsigned __int64>,std::equal_to<unsigned __int64>,std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned __int64 const ,stMappingElem_t> > >::unordered_map<unsigned __int64,stMappingElem_t,std::hash<unsigned __int6()
    g:\mywork\src\datamapmanager.cpp (15): example.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'sm_eventDataMapList''() + 0xD bytes
    d:\rs1\minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\startup\initterm.cpp (22): ucrtbased.dll!_initterm()
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl (221): example.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh() + 0xF bytes
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl (296): example.exe!__scrt_common_main()
    f:\dd\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_main.cpp (17): example.exe!mainCRTStartup()
    KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk() + 0x24 bytes
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x2F bytes
    ntdll.dll!_RtlUserThreadStart() + 0x1B bytes
  Data:
    38 09 E6 00    F0 98 E8 00    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     8....... ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD     ........ ........
    CD CD CD CD    CD CD CD CD                                   ........ ........
```

More maps: common.h

```
using namespace std;

#ifdef USE_64BIT
typedef uint64_t   ID;
#else
typedef uint32_t   ID;
#endif

typedef ID EVENT_UID;

struct stEventParams_t {
    EVENT_UID  m_unEventID;
    uint8_t    *m_ptrMemAddr;
    size_t     m_dataSize;
} ;

struct stTagElem_t {
    uint32_t  m_unOffset;
    uint32_t  m_unArraySize;
    string    m_acTagName;
    string    m_acTagValue;
    string    m_acDataType;
} ;

typedef std::unordered_map<uint8_t, stTagElem_t> tagsList_t;

struct stMappingElem_t {
    uint16_t     m_unMemSize;
    tagsList_t   m_stTagsList;
    string       m_acEventName;
    string       m_acMapTypeName;
} ;

typedef std::unordered_map<EVENT_UID, stMappingElem_t> eventDataMap_t;

struct stAppBlocInfo_t {
    string   m_acAppBlocName;
    string   m_acInstanceName;
    string   m_acDataMap_r_SPError;
    string   m_acTypeName;
} ;

typedef std::unordered_map<string, string> instanceTypeList_t;

typedef struct {
    stAppBlocInfo_t    m_acServiceProvider;
    instanceTypeList_t m_acParamsList;
} stSP_Params_t;

typedef std::unordered_map<string, stSP_Params_t> serviceProvider_t;

struct stServiceParams_t {
    bool               m_bIsItOutput;
    uint8_t            m_unIdxToEvtClient;
    EVENT_UID          m_unEventID;
    string             m_acInstanceName;
    string             m_acTypeName;
    instanceTypeList_t m_acParamsList;
} ;

typedef std::unordered_map<ID, stServiceParams_t> serviceParams_t;

struct stStatusElem_t {
    bool                m_bErrorPresent;
    std::string         m_acSPError;
    instanceTypeList_t  m_ServiceStatus;
};

typedef std::unordered_map<CSI_base *, stSP_Params_t > spInstanceList_t;
typedef CSI_base* (*CREATE_SI)(stSP_Params_t, eventDataMap_t, serviceParams_t);
typedef std::map<std::string, HINSTANCE> extnSiObjList_t;
struct AppBloc_Elements {
APPBLOCNAME      m_acAppBlocName;
CFBNwExecutor   *ptrFbnExec;
};

typedef std::map<APPLET_ID, AppBloc_Elements> AppBlocElemList;
typedef std::map<APPBLOCNAME, APPLET_ID> AppBlocsList;
```

My entire application consists of 50+ cpp file were I was using standard STL library on most use cases.

Comment: "specifically where ever I used STL library and `new` operator" -- there's your problem, no need to allocate space for STL container instances using `new`.

Comment: There's no such thing as the STL anymore, not the way you're using the term. It's all called the "standard library."

Comment: read up on [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: You do not need to delete elements from standard containers before clearing them, unless they contain owning raw pointers or other raw owning handle. `tagsList_t` and `eventDataMap_t` do not have any raw owning pointers, you do not have to worry about these type of containers leaking.

Comment: Nothing from the code you are showing looks like a memory leak.  If you have one you will need to provide a [mcve] to get help.

Comment: I refer to the following link which says more about STL containers and memory usage. http://lemire.me/blog/2016/09/15/the-memory-usage-of-stl-containers-can-be-surprising/ and http://info.prelert.com/blog/stl-container-memory-usage

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Thanks for your info. That was only one std::map I had shown as example. In my actual code I have several std::map which has std::string and class pointers. Will those cause issues?

Comment: Good: 1.) You are using the standard library: 2.) You measure memory leaks. Bad: 1.) You use unnecessary dynamic allocation. 2.) You do not post an MCVE. 3.) You call the standard library STL. 4.) You use `using namespace std;`. 5.) All your struct names start with `st`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: which part of the code you mention as unnecessary dynamic allocation? Regarding MCVE: My entire application uses those map,set, dqueue container and I hope its very hard to place all the stuff.

Comment: @yuvi: The unncessary dynamic allocation is presumably that which is caused by your use of `new`. Which you do not show. Please post an MCVE. It may be hard, but you need one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question "will the STL library create memory leak every time I access it?" is **no**. Standard library containers do allocate memory as needed for their operations but you'd have to try very hard to make them actually leak *their own* memory. VLD output you provided shows memory allocated by unordered_map; it is not leaked, it is used by that map to store your data. If you clear the map, this memory will be freed.

There are two possibilities for why your memory usage goes up. First is, you might be pushing more and more data into some container indefinitely. E.g. you might be creating new events and placing them into `sm_eventDataMapList` without removing old events. In this case memory has to go up, no matter whether it is standard containers or your hand-rolled structures. This is reasonably easy to spot with VLD as it will show more and more allocations in some specific place over time. This is not a leak in containers, this is error in your code.

Second possibility, and probably this is that happens to you - is that you are leaking memory allocated by `new`. It is **your** responsibility to delete all objects allocated with `new` whether they are no longer used. Containers won't do that automatically. Smart pointers can to help you with this task, but I recommend to take a hard look at all places where you are using `new` and think if you *really* need to allocate the object in this way. Often you can do things differently and get much more simpler and safer code.

E.g. in this case: `unordered_map<CSI_base *, stSP_Params_t >` - use are using pointer to an object as a key. Are you `delete`ing or otherwise disposing of that object once you've removed that element from the map?

Another example:

```
struct stEventParams_t {
    EVENT_UID  m_unEventID;
    uint8_t    *m_ptrMemAddr;
    size_t     m_dataSize;
} ;
```

I'm going to assume this structure owns memory pointed to by `m_ptrMemAddr`, and `m_dataSize` is a size of that memory block. In this case you need to remember to `delete[]` this memory every time you are removing `stEventParams_t` instance, which is very easy to forget.

Better way - make the structure remove owned resources:

```
struct stEventParams_t {
    ~stEventParams_t() {delete[] m_ptrMemAddr;}
    EVENT_UID  m_unEventID;
    uint8_t    *m_ptrMemAddr;
    size_t     m_dataSize;
} ;
```

Even better - use smart pointer for that:

```
struct stEventParams_t {
    EVENT_UID  m_unEventID;
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> m_ptrMemAddr;
    size_t     m_dataSize;
} ;
```

And even better - use appropriate standard container (cannot leak memory and no need for separate `size` as container knows its length):

```
struct stEventParams_t {
    EVENT_UID  m_unEventID;
    std::vector<uint8_t> m_data;
} ;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your detailing. My real concern in case of CSI_base * is that is an external shared library. I need to create CSI_base object and call an initialization function. Once this is done I need to call send/receive function which is inside the shared library. As I need to create several such object I stored that object pointer in an unordered_map. If I delete the CSI_base * after initialization I wouldn't be able to use it for send/receive. For example I will create 20 such objects. Will this frequent send/receive calls creates any impact on memory?